# Researched, but still really confused about Vi vs. Vim

Tags: centos, vim, vi, editors

My first post on `unix.stackexchange.com`. Please, don't just react by the title of this post as I'm not jumping in having not researched what I'm asking for.

I have done quite a research about `Vi` vs. `Vim` topic. As several forums, and as also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61021/vi-vs-vim-or-is-there-any-reason-why-i-would-ever-want-to-use-vi), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63708/what-are-some-of-the-main-differences-between-vim-and-vi) or [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/biggest-differences-between-vim-and-vi) threads speak, **Vim** is a superset of **Vi**, adding quite a lot of useful perks on top.

**Confusion #1**
However, right now, I'm doing a bit of in-depth Linux course (want to learn this OS better), and The Linux Foundation instructor says, that:

> usually, installed program on the distribution is **Vim**, and **Vi** just links to it as an alias.

This seems plausible, as disregarding of whether I open **vi** or **vim** from my terminal, **absolutely identical** welcome screen launches, with identical software name, version, author and etc..

**Confusion #2**
However, **which vim** and **which vi** print different files from `/usr/bin/` directory.

So, I'm really confused, because on one hand a lot of people speak that **Vim** is a superset of **Vi**, but on the other hand, the course I'm doing now says, that it's both **Vim**, and opening **vi** or **vim**, actually, *almost*<sup>(as they show up as identical software but behave differently)</sup> proves it.

**Confusion #3**
So,

1. Why people say, that **Vi** and **Vim** are two different programs and that **Vim** is a superset of **Vi**? as they even have identical welcome screen and version numbers, at least, on CentOS 7;
2. or maybe **Vi** is an alias of **Vim** specifically on CentOS 7 (which I'm using now) and usually (on other OSes) they are two different programs? but then again, they are two different binaries.. but they have **absolutely identical** welcome screen, which is really confusing;
3. If they are not different, why opening my `.java` source file is highlighted when I open it with **vim** and - is not, when I open it with **vi**?

I'm sorry if this text is a bit mashed up, but that is exactly what confuses me, as well, and what is the whole information I have gathered and observed.

They seem to be same (also are claimed by the instructor), but they are told to be different (on different forums) and they actually behave (this java file case) and show up (with **which**) as different.

So, what shall I understand from this?

### Update:

As asked to do, `vi --version` and `vim --version` output this:

**`vi --version`:**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 15 2020 16:43:23)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

**`vim --version`:**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 15 2020 16:44:08)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

Comment: They output `/usr/bin/vim` and `/usr/bin/vi` respectively.

Comment: Also, as far as I understand, **symlink** is a soft link, which is just a reference/shortcut.. so why they are two distinct binaries and why they act differently for my `.java` file?

Comment: I did `file /usr/bin/vi` and `file /usr/bin/vim`. They output: `vi: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9e160471d61f662dedf0d6a550962b864dc92f76, stripped` and `vim: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=3dc92fe1ec8c5aa3d85b11ff67c0300b966f46b9, stripped` respectively.

Comment: @Quasímodo your guess, that one might call another, seems logical to me.. as they, by all signs, seem to be two distinct binaries/software packages. So, one might indeed be calling another.. can I look it up if one calls another and how exactly (with what arguments/options) it does, if so?

Comment: `rpm -qf /usr/bin/vi` => `vim-minimal-7.4.629-8.el7_9.x86_64`; and `rpm -qf /usr/bin/vim` => `vim-enhanced-7.4.629-8.el7_9.x86_64`. `-q` is for query, and `-f` for Query package owning FILE, in RHEL family. So, does this mean that they are different programs but very similar? is my guess correct? how come that even versioning numbers, release dates, and everything else match then?..

Comment: `vim-minimal` is a stripped down version (more like `vi`) without syntax-highlighting, compare the feature lists of `vi --version` and `vim --version`.

Comment: @Freddy please have a look at the update.

Comment: Also, I really would appreciate the reason of downvoting.. I'm not hunting for votes.. but I also don't think, that this questions deserved a downvote. I really have approached and researched this from different angles.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I cannot tell for sure since I didn't downvote, but the way your post is structured can be interpreted as containing several problems at once, which would violate the "one question per post" rule. Also, I found it somewhat difficult to understand what kind of answer (in particular how much in-depth) you would like to get to your question; this may also attract downvotes.

Comment: @AdminBee I think I know how the StackExchange sites work, in general, and this is not my first question. It's just first on unix site, but general rules of thumb apply everywhere. I don't agree that my question contains several problems - it clearly states that the only problem here is `vi` vs. `vim`; however, another story is **where and in what circumstances** I find these two to be counterintuitive, which I explain as thoroughly as I can. Thank you for your points, but I don't think I agree with them, and my question doesn't violate "one question per post". Your second point is unclear.

Comment: I think your question is pretty appropriate for [unix.se], since there are many points on the versions shipped by CentOS, the two RPM packages and so on... If you have more questions on Vim (or Vi, or the history of them), there's also a [vi.se] stack for you, you'll be very welcome there!

Answer (score 3):

The original vi was created by Bill Joy in 1976. The vi editor has since been re-implemented several times, and the name vi is now used in the sense "any program that roughly implements the commands and keybindings of the original vi." You could say that vi has lost its trademark, just like the words "Aspirin" and "Escalator."

Vim is said to be superset of vi because it implements a lot more features than the original vi, but still roughly remains compatible with "vi".

The reason both the commands `vi` and `vim` exist on your machine is that there are some (perceived) uses for a program that behaves exactly like "vi". The `vi` program is smaller, so it starts up faster. Vim might do some editing commands a bit differently, which may be considered wrong. This is especially important when vi commands are scripted, and the output is required to be "just right" if it is consumed by some other program or script.

The same design has been applied with the Bash shell, which is two programs in one. When invoked as `sh`, Bash mimics the original `/bin/sh`, i.e. it restricts its features and in some ways behaves a bit differently than when invoked as `bash`.

The reason you see the same welcome screen and matching version numbers is that both programs come from the same source, and are developed in tandem. They probably even share the same source code.

Comment: So, they are different software programs, but they have identical version strings, identical build numbers, identical names.. and everything copycatted? well, a super bad manner and style to release the software then. One is not born with all this knowledge and it's 100% confusing if you just happen to want to learn about them. How this non-descriptive-at-all two executables should be differentiated.. strange.. and now this is a discouraging point for me in Linux.. although I really like a lot of things in this OS.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri They are one and the same program, from [GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim), but in your system `vi` is the executable built with less features and `vim` with more features. The original Vi can still be found at http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/, but no mainline distro seems to be willing to use it as long as there is Vim around.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Vi is a editor mandated by POSIX, the Portable Operating System Interface family of standards, which Linux distributions try to adhere to. POSIX also says the name of the editor is `vi`. Other standard utility programs originated from Unix and specified by POSIX are sh, ls, cp, mv, rm, cat, sed, awk, wc, grep, and so on. None of these programs in a modern Linux distribution have any source code common with the original Unix versions of the programs, they are all "copycatted".

Comment: @JohanMyréen thank you, but I don't wanna lie and show up as it's crystal-clear now. I understand, that there is a history, an inheritance and etc. also, I understand, that lots of utility programs are originated from old Unix. Still.. my questions seem to me crystal-clearly simple:
1) are these two (vi/vim) same? seems like not, at least on CentOS;
2) why the Linux Foundation (should be best) instructors say, `vi` is usually symlink to `vim`? not on CentOS, as I can see;
3) Different builds, with different options, **are different software programs**, even if they come from same source.

Comment: So, why they just mirror each other bit by bit, in build versions and every other metainformation? don't you agree that this is extremely misleading and wrong? it's like they **clearly** are different (doesn't matter that source is same.. final builds differ), but they don't even mention this in the metainformation/description. This is not cool.. at all.. imagine a person who is aspiring to learn Linux.. how should one get this clear in their brain? I'm not a "ok, doesn't matter" person.. and I try to pay attention to every single bit of information.. and vi and vim are so popular.. pity.

Comment: It is probably a matter of semantics, on which there will be a division of opinion, as to whether two binaries produced from the same source code but from different compilation flags should have the same version number.  To me, it is similar to how the latest debian release is 10.7.0, which is shipped as, for example, debian-10.7.0-amd64-netinst.iso, debian-10.7.0-i386-netinst.iso etc.

Comment: Also, in reponse to your comment on my answer: that is odd that `/usr/bin/vi --version` and `/usr/bin/vim --version` don't show you the features they are compiled with.  When I run this on a computer running CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 they have a 41-line output which includes a table of features.  I must admit that I have not adminstered CentOS for a long time but do have access to a computer running it to issue those commands, so there may be subtleties to their package management that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Vim and vi are different programs. Vim is an extended version of vi, that's why it is named differently: "vim = vi improved". A POSIX compliant system must include a program called `vi`, that should be compatible with the original vi, but can implement extensions, as long as they are not incompatible with the original vi. This is why some distros make vi a symlink to vim, so you can invoke the editor using the command `vi`. Red Hat apparently took a different route, and provides a differently configured minimal vim as `vi`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.
"that's why it is named vim = vi improved" makes sense, but same "vim = Vi IMproved" opens when I open `vi`.
So, overall, with all the comments and input, I deduce following, and please correct me if I still get it wrong:

1. Generally, `vi` and `vim` are different, and `vim` is a superset (extension) of `vi`; 2. on some Linux distributions, `vi` just symlinks to `vim`, but on others - they are distinct binaries (doesn't matter where they were compiled from - resulting binaries are different); 3. Usually, both are built from the same source-code (w/ different flags).

Answer (score 2):

Vim is indeed derived from Bill Joy's original vi.  However, nowadays because development on vim is significantly greater than vi, many distros (including CentOS) emulate the original vi behaviour using vim compiled with fewer features.

To answer your questions/confusions:

1. When you open vi, it opens the same start screen as vim (which describes itself as vim) because it is in fact a stripped-down vim that you are running, not the original vi.
2. `/usr/bin/vi` and `/usr/bin/vim` are different binaries because they are both actually compiled from vim's source code but with different features (options).
3. Syntax highlighting is not available when you use `vi file.java` but is for `vim file.java` because of the different options they have been compiled with.  If you look closely at the output of `/usr/bin/vim --version` and `/usr/bin/vi --version` you will see that the former show `+syntax`, amongst other features, whereas the latter has `-syntax`.  That list is what I am referring to regarding "features it has been compiled with".

I hope that helps, and can see why it might be confusing.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Just don't wanna copy-paste the same comments, and please have a look at our discussion in another answer's comments. P. S. `--version` don't output different strings.. see the update in the question. They never mention anything like +syntax.

Answer (score 1):

From your `vi --version` and `vim --version` outputs:

```
vi --version:

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 15 2020 16:43:23)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):


vim --version:

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 15 2020 16:44:08)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

... I would conclude the following:

At Dec 15 2020, 16:43:23 of whatever timezone RedHat's package builder was using, it unpacked the `vim 7.4` source code, applied a large number of patches to it, and then set out to build a binary with a set of compile-time configuration settings that was designed to be as compact as possible and maximally compatible with the classic `vi`, even if that meant disabling user-friendliness features. The resulting binary was to be named `/usr/bin/vi`. This would be packaged as the RPM package `vim-minimal`.

Note: although the resulting binary is named `vi`, this is still unquestionably Vim - just in `vi` compatibility mode by default.

Then, at 16:44:08, another package build job started with the same source code and patches, but with different compile-time configuration settings. This job was configured to build a more modern, more featureful configuration, even though it would consume somewhat more disk space and might be very slightly different from the classic `vi` in some respects. The binary resulting from this compilation would be named `/usr/bin/vim` and packaged as `vim-enhanced`.

(Since this version says `Small version without GUI`, it is not the version packaged as `vim-X11` - that would be a third build run and a yet another RPM package.)

---

The original `vi` was written by Bill Joy in the 1970s, released as part of BSD Unix in 1978, and since then licensed to various commercial Unixes. In 1983, the ownership of the codebase was adopted by AT&T as part of their UNIX System V. As a result, until the licensing rules were relaxed in 2002, only people and companies with an AT&T source license could distribute `vi`. And so, people looking for a free Unix-style editor started to write clones of the original `vi`, in order to have a version that would work the same but was free of the costly license requirement.

`vim` was one of these clones, with enhancements. It was released to the public in 1991 and since then been subject for much cross-platform development. This made it more featureful than the original `vi`, and it's probably currently the most widespread of the clones of `vi`.

RedHat's packaging of Vim splits the binaries generated from single source code package into several RPM binary packages: `vim-common`, `vim-filesystem`, `vim-minimal`, `vim-enhanced` and `vim-X11`. Of these, `vim-filesystem` defines some directories where other packages may drop in syntax or filetype definitions or other files that add functionality to Vim. `vim-common` depends on the `vim-filesystem`package and contains files required by `vim-enhanced` or `vim-X11`. The online help files within `vim-common` are also usable by `vim-minimal` but not strictly required.

The `vim-minimal` provides `[/usr]/bin/vi`, and also binaries `/usr/bin/ex`, `/usr/bin/rvi`,  `/usr/bin/[r]view`, configuration file `/etc/virc` and their man pages.

`vim-enhanced` provides `/usr/bin/vim` with more modern compile-time configuration defaults, but still with terminal-based UI only. It explicitly requires Perl and `vim-common`. `vim-X11` provides a version of Vim with full X11 GUI and mouse support (with a binary named `/usr/bin/gvim`), and has the same requirements as `vim-enhanced` plus a set of X11 icons and libraries.

Even if you select "minimal installation" in the RedHat installer, it will probably include `vim-minimal`. But the `vim-enhanced` or `vim-X11` will be completely optional.

If you want to understand the process at a deeper level, I would urge you to download the corresponding `.src.rpm` package from which all these binary RPMs are built, extract it into an empty directory, and study the `vim.spec` file at the root directory. That file includes the exact configuration options for each version of Vim.

If you are interested in the traditional `vi`, [you can find it at ex-vi.sourceforge.net](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/). But most modern Linux distributions (that are not aiming for embedded platforms or otherwise restricting themselves for absolute minimum size) are likely to use Vim as a replacement of traditional `vi`.

Comment: @tecoM thank you very much for your contribution. I'll have some time to parse everything you wrote step by step, and I'll get back with my comment. I just happen not to be actively surfing the web these days.. which might be the reason of a bit delayed reply.